# Instruments > Automation - stops with "Script was stopped by the user"

Tags: instruments, ui-automation

When running a script in the Automation tool of Instruments I'm starting to get these errors when I click Start:

```
Script was stopped by the user
```

Any idea why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This happened usually when your script is illegal.

I met this error once when I captured too much interactions at one time. I delete some of the lines then it worked.

Hope is helpful: )

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click the switch to enable UI Automation.

Comment: do you need to reboot or anything afterwards?  still getting error once that is enabled.